# Project Euler #34: Digit factorials - review code : Java

Tags: java

A digital factorial need to be found out. This no. is easily divisible by sum of factorials of all the digits of the no.
I am trying this on HackerRank : https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler034/

My code is passing only one test case i.e. if n < 20.Other test cases are not passing.

Code is below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int len,newt=0,pos = 0,ans=0;
        long fac,sum;
        for(int i=10;i<=n;i++){
            newt  = i;
            sum =0;
            len = String.valueOf(newt).length();         
        while(len>0){
            fac=1;
        pos = newt % 10;
        newt = newt/10;              
        for(int k=1;k<=pos;k++){
       fac = fac*k;     
        } 
            sum+=fac;        
        len--;
        }
      //      System.out.print(sum+" "+i);
      //      System.out.println();
                if(sum%i==0){
            ans = i;
        }
        }
       System.out.print(ans);
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you traced through this code in the debugger?  What did you find?

Comment: @JorgeCampos No, it is off-topic there as the code does not currently work.

Comment: Ok, I will retract the vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for iterating the digits of a number `n` seems overly complex. It's a simple as this:

```
if (n <= 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a positive number: " + n);
for (; n > 0; n /= 10) {
    int digit = n % 10;
    // use digit here
}
```

Your code can also be improved by using methods to separate the logic into independent parts, e.g.

```
private static int sumCuriousNumbers(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 10; i <= n; i++)
        if (isCuriousNumber(i))
            sum += i;
    return sum;
}
private static boolean isCuriousNumber(int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = number; i > 0; i /= 10)
        sum += factorial(i % 10);
    return (sum % number == 0);
}
private static int factorial(int n) {
    int f = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        f *= i;
    return f;
}
```

This helps document the code and the 3 methods can now be unit-tested too.